# Switch string contains or startswith

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for an example of code for "switch" string that will switch strings basing on StartsWith or Contains or EndsWith and other. I'd like to change the code below with that switch.

```
        if (item.Contains("Passwords"))
        {
            _modelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Text1");
        }
        else if (item.StartsWith("Email") && item.EndsWith("is already taken."))
        {
            _modelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Text2");
        }
        else
        {
            _modelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, item);
        }
```

Comment: What's wrong with this `if-else` structure? Why do you want to change it?

Comment: Yes, i've just realized that in that case there is no reason to change it to switch as there is an else if. Sorry for the trouble.